# Routing of PCB layout/layout review after the schematics

Tags: pcb, layout

How do I learn PCB layout review by myself?

Comment: Using google/bing/other search engine. Then lots of experience and practice.

Comment: A big issue is interference. Magnetic-field induced errors are easily found: Vinduce = 2e-7 * Area/Distance * dI/dT. Consider a 1cm*1cm loop, located 1cm from a power-supplier rectifier for a microwave oven having dI/dT of 100amps/1uSecond. The Vinduce = 2e-7 * 1cm * 10^8 amp/second = 2e-9 * e+8 = 0.2 volts induced into your circuit, at 60Hz rate. Are you willing to think about those interferences?

Answer (score 3):

I would try taking it step by step.

First try to grasp the basics, look up some basic rules, reducing loops to minimum, try to read into some grounding practices(Which is already a huge subject), read about decoupling/bypass capacitors. There are a huge amount of tutorials, guidelines and videos on the subjects to be found. On youtube, Udemy or where ever.

Open a datasheet or application data of a chip (maybe even open source project), and look at recommended board layouts. Try to figure out why people place stuff the way they did. Why is this clockline not next to this switching power supply, why is this filter placed so close together. Try to think that everyone was placed at that location for a reason. And figure out that reason. One of the most valuable learning aspects is trying to understand what other experienced designers did.

Choose a tool you want to use for designing the circuits boards, Altium, Eagle, Kicad, EasyEDA. Whatever you feel like. And get acquinted with the tool, learn how to place polygons, or fills, how to place via's and how to build up a multilayer pcb stack. Eventually figure out how to do length and differential matching.

Finally think about the pcb you want to create, will it be used for RF communication, read into it. Will it be for a switching power supply, explore this field. Every subjects requires a new area of attention.
And every pcb I make requires me to read into new subjects at great depth before starting the design.